# How to get feeds on Editing of File in Chatter?

Tags: chatter, files

I want to know that, is there any way to get feeds on changes of Files. I am getting feeds for file creation and uploading new versions; however I want feeds/notifications on File name editing/description editing.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible with out of box options .I tried with the Feed Tracking but unfortunately changes we do on the Name or description is tracked in Content version object .

Good news is that You can write triggers on content version object .Here is simple trigger i tried which works

```
 trigger notifyFileNameChangesc on ContentVersion (after update) {
 list<FeedItem> lstfeeditems = new list<FeedItem>();
  for(ContentVersion  c:trigger.new){
   if(trigger.oldmap.get(c.id).Description!=c.Description){
        FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
        post.ParentId = userinfo.getuserId(); //eg. Opportunity id, custom object id..
        post.Body = 'Description value changed from ' + trigger.oldmap.get(c.id).Description+ ' to '+c.Description;
        lstfeeditems.add(post);
   }
   if(trigger.oldmap.get(c.id).Title!=c.Title){
        FeedItem post = new FeedItem();
        post.ParentId = userinfo.getuserId(); //eg. Opportunity id, custom object id..
        post.Body = 'Name value changed from ' + trigger.oldmap.get(c.id).Title+ ' to '+c.Title;
        lstfeeditems.add(post);
   }
 }

 insert lstfeeditems;
}
```

Please note its just dirty at this point and you can improve with best practices of having logic in single class ,using labels for hardcoded texts.